# Extract a word from a sentence in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to extract a certain word from a sentence and store it in a variable in Perl. I don't quite understand match groups and how it works. For example, I want to extract Sammy from `My name is Sammy Tyrell`.

I have this:

```
^((M|m)y name is\s)|((I|i) am\s)?[(A-Za-z)]*
```

And this is matching `Sammy Tyrell`. But I don't know how to extract `Sammy` from it.

Comment: Please refer to a tutorial, e.g. http://regexone.com as this is a really basic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this perhaps

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $s = 'My name is Sammy Tyrell';

say $1 if $s =~/(?:my name is|i am) (\S+)/i;
```

#### output

```
Sammy
```

`(?: ... )` groups text without capturing it

The `/i` modifier enables case-independent matching, to avoid having to write `(M|m)y` etc.

The `\S` matches any non-space character, so `(\S+)` matches and captures all of `Sammy`